# Is it possible to create an IP address radix in modelsim?

Tags: modelsim

Is there anyway to make ip address words display in the decimal dotted format in the waves window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, not...
But you could create virtual signals for the 4 parts ('virtual signal ...').
Display those as decimal ('-radix unsigned').
And create a group with those 4 virtual signals ('add wave ... -group ...) .

I found creating virtual signals and groups easier in the GUI then typing it yourself in the DO file ('Tools' -> 'Virtual Builder').

A  test VHDL file:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test is
end entity test;

architecture rtl of test is
    signal ip : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"AC_10_41_3D";  -- 172.16.65.61
begin  -- architecture rtl
end architecture rtl;
```

The important parts of a wave.do file:

```
quietly virtual signal -install /test { /test/ip(31 downto 24)} ip_3
quietly virtual signal -install /test { /test/ip(23 downto 16)} ip_2
quietly virtual signal -install /test { /test/ip(15 downto 8)} ip_1
quietly virtual signal -install /test { /test/ip(7 downto 0)} ip_0
add wave -noupdate /test/ip; # without formatting
# group the 4 parts of the IP address and display them as decimal
add wave -noupdate -expand -group {IP_formatted} -radix unsigned /test/ip_3
add wave -noupdate -expand -group {IP_formatted} -radix unsigned /test/ip_2
add wave -noupdate -expand -group {IP_formatted} -radix unsigned /test/ip_1
add wave -noupdate -expand -group {IP_formatted} -radix unsigned /test/ip_0
```